# Magento 2 - Admin grid and export use different timezone

Tags: admin, export, date, timezone

I'm using Magento 2. So, I created a Adminhtml data grid in a custom module. The problem is that the data grid doesn't match the exported data. I've set the timezone, but it seems data grid and exported data use different time base.

Below is the code I use to show created_at attribute.

```
<column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date">
        <settings>
            <filter>dateRange</filter>
            <dataType>date</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Created At</label>
            <sorting>asc</sorting>
        </settings>
    </column>
```

Tell me if you need more information regarding this problem. Any hint is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: please share your 'created_at' column xml code.

Comment: Please check the updated question @FaisalSheikh

Comment: please try below code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found an answer for this problem. Please do comment if there's anything wrong about this answer.

Basically we have to add metadataprovider configuration in

> [ModuleName]/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Ui\Model\Export\MetadataProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="customer_note_listing" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="created_at" xsi:type="string">created_at</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

This will register our component name which is then checked in convertDate method in

> Magento/Module-Ui/Model/Export/MetadataProvider.php.

Comment: What is customer_note_listing?

Comment: Your answer is right bro. Where customer_note_listing is the Uicomponent name

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code for created_at column:

```
<column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created at</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

Hope it's help you.

Comment: It doesn't work. Exportbutton is supposed to be using what data grid has, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it's working on my side.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work on my side. Thank you for trying anyway! Cheers